# Issue with MySQL fetch for events based on date with custom date format and with MySQL condition like events passing through dates

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp-1.3

I am loading all events and displaying it on a calender month wise. When i click on a day like 21-07-2014 it will fetch all records in that date and show it no the right side of calender via ajax. What i am trying to achieve is that, i want to fetch all events in 21-07-2014 and also events having start at 10-07-2014 and ends on ex: '31-07-2014'(Any events passing through given event date)

Event start date field is event_date and event end date field is end_date

Event Table Structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `events` (
  `event_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `event_title` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `event_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `end_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `location` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` text,
  `event_photo` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `thumbnail` text NOT NULL,
  `photo` text NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `event_share_type` enum('1','0') DEFAULT NULL,
  `delete_status` enum('1','0') DEFAULT '0',
  `remarks` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `status` enum('1','0') DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`event_id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `delete_status` (`delete_status`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `event_id` (`event_id`,`user_id`,`created_date`,`delete_status`,`status`,`event_share_type`,`end_date`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `remarks` (`remarks`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `status` (`status`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

This is my Mysql Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `Events`.`event_id` as id, `Events`.`event_title` AS `title`,
'Events`.`event_date` AS `start`, `Events`.`end_date` AS `end` FROM `events` AS `Events` 
WHERE ((`Events`.`end_date` >= DATE("2014-07-10")) OR (`Events`.`event_date` LIKE '%2014-07-10%') OR (`Events`.`end_date` LIKE '%2014-07-10%')) AND `Events`.`delete_status` = '0' AND `Events`.`status` = '1' ORDER BY `Events`.`created_date` ASC;
```

This is CakePhp find:

```
$this->Events->find('all', array(
            'joins'=>$joins,
            'conditions' => array(
                'OR'=>array('Events.end_date >= DATE("'.$dateFormat.'")','Events.event_date LIKE' => "%".$dateFormat."%",'Events.end_date LIKE' => "%".$dateFormat."%")
                ,'Events.delete_status'=>'0','Events.status'=>'1','CP.circuit_id IN '.$my_circuits,'CP.circuit_post_id' => 2,'CP.delete_status'=>'0','CP.status'=>'Y'),
            'order'=>'Events.created_date ASC',  
            'fields'=>array('DISTINCT Events.event_id as id','Events.event_title as title','Events.event_date as start','Events.end_date as end')
        ));
```

Comment: actually this is the MySQL dump for CakePhp generated find of events. Its working perfectly except the condition to get events passing through the given date say current date.

Comment: End_date can be greater than, equal to, or LIKE 'x'. How does *that* work!?!

Comment: yup they are datetime fields

Comment: So the wildcard at the beginning of the date can serve no purpose. Get rid of it because it can only make things really slow.

Comment: Beyond that, and if you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you've not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you've not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: updated my question with my table structure...

Comment: SQL FIDDLE: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ca8ad/3

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for events that start sometime before the end (23:59:59) of the selected day and end sometime after the start (00:00:00) of the selected day.

Try these adjustments to your cakephp query:

```
$conditions = array('Events.event_date <' => $dateFormat.' 23:59:59',
                    'Events.end_date >' => $dateFormat.' 00:00:00',
                    'Events.delete_status' => '0',
                    'Events.status' => '1'
                    'CP.circuit_id IN '.$my_circuits,
                    'CP.circuit_post_id' => 2,
                    'CP.delete_status' => '0'
                    'CP.status'=>'Y');
$this->Events->find('all', array(
            'joins' => $joins,
            'conditions' => $conditions,
            'order'=>'Events.created_date ASC',  
            'fields'=>array('DISTINCT Events.event_id as id','Events.event_title as title','Events.event_date as start','Events.end_date as end')
        ));
```

Also according to the [cakephp documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Models.html#complex-find-conditions) if you can turn $my_circuits into an array you could use this line in the condition instead of the `'CP.circuit_id IN '.$my_circuits` SQL fragment.

```
"CP.circuit_id" => $my_circuits
```

The demonstration given in the documentation is:

> Let’s say you wanted to find posts where the title was in a given set of values:

```
array(
    "Post.title" => array("First post", "Second post", "Third post")
)
```